# Hide 'Range Input' button in mobile full screen of highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highcharts module and in mobile screen, I need to remove the 'Range Input' option when a user views the chart in full-screen mode. I have tried with export option, but it is not working. This is my sample code,

```
 exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      rangeSelector: {
      inputEnabled: false,
      },
    },
 },
```

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `enabled: false` in the `rangeSelector` configuration objcet:

```
rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2rgb4w9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.enabled

Comment: I need to hide the 'Range Input' for the full-screen view only. That too I need in mobile devices. Can I do that?

Comment: Hi @hakkim, You can use `responsive` option for that: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/responsive.rules.condition